# How do I select the most recent element?

Tags: xml, string, xpath, timestamp, string-comparison

I have an XML document with a bunch of elements, each containing a timestamp attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dfs:myFields xmlns:dfs="<url>">
    <dfs:dataFields>
        <dfs:yobeans Title="test1.xml" Modified="2011-06-07 10:03:52"/>
        <dfs:yobeans Title="test2.xml" Modified="2011-06-07 10:43:17"/>
        <dfs:yobeans Title="test3.xml" Modified="2011-06-07 10:43:27"/>
        <dfs:yobeans Title="test4.xml" Modified="2011-06-07 11:42:27"/>
        <dfs:yobeans Title="test5.xml" Modified="2011-06-07 11:42:38"/>
        <dfs:yobeans Title="test6.xml" Modified="2011-06-07 11:42:47"/>
    </dfs:dataFields>
</dfs:myFields>
```

Is it possible to use XPath 1.0 to select the most recent element? I have seen some people who claim they did it somehow with string comparison but did not specify how.

Comment: Looking at your XML isn't the most recent always the first one?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately I can't count on that always being the case. Some of them might get modified after having been created.

Comment: Thought: How about if I removed all the ' ','-', and ':' from them and sorted them like that? XPath 1.0 has weak typing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is in yyyy-mm-dd format and the time is in 24 hour format and leading zeros are used everywhere, the text will sort in date-time order.

Comment: So does that mean I can just grab the first element even if the timestamps are not in the right order in the actual xml?

Comment: No.  The sorting still has to be performed.  I was just pointing out that if datetimes as text are configured correctly they will sort correctly:  You still have to sort them.   Here's a Microsoft article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.addsort%28VS.71%29.aspx